# When does the JSX context start?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Pardon me if my question seems incomprehensible.
So, I'm currently learning React at FreeCodeCamp and I find it confusing as to when I should use the curly braces to include javascript.
So to keep it short, do I use the `{ }` whenever I'm between tags like `<h1></h1>`.
Should the file containing JSX be `file.js` or `file.jsx`.
If it's `file.js`, how can we not get errors due to js syntax.

Comment: You can check this link https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Comment: File extension is not too important, different semantics. Yes curly braces allow you to put js **expressions**, not statements inside jsx element tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whenever you want to use javascript within HTML in a react component, you should use curly braces. Sometimes, you may have a situation where you have some outer html element, then you have curly braces to perform some logic and then another html element. For example:

```
render( <div>{ this.listOfItems.map(item => <h1>{item}<h1> ) }</div> )
```

In general, round brackets allow you to write html, curly brackets allow you to write javascript.

Also, convention is react is written in .jsx files but .js files should work fine in most IDE's.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you want to refer to some variables or do some simple JS logic, you use the curly braces `{ }`. Technically everything inside the JSX file is inside a JSX context. JSX is an extension of Javascript that allows us to write code that looks like html(like the h1 tags), but in reality the code is still Javascript. During runtime, the code that looks like html is translated to Javascript. And the file should be named `file.jsx` not `file.js`.